# MVC item does not exist in the context. What is wrong?

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

I made a page in MVC where you can save multiple records. This worked all fine. Now I wanted to get the item id of one of the records im saving. I used

```
int newPeriodId = db.Periods.Max(item => item.Id);
```

this integer now contains the correct Id. Im saving data like this:

```
foreach (var item in Model.Evaluation)
    item.PeriodId = newPeriodId;
    db.Evaluations.Add(item);
```

The error shows up at (item). without `item.PeriodId = newPeriodId;` the error doesnt show.
How can I fix this?

Comment: The whole error is: ```The name 'item' does not exist in the current context```

Comment: Looks like missing bracket :)

Comment: Put the body of the foreach statement in curly braces: {}

Comment: I c#, for those types of statements, (foreach, for, if, etc.), if there is no `{}` then it only executes the next instruction up to `;`. So this only had access to `item` in line 2, and by line 3, it was out of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use braces for this

```
    foreach (var item in Model.Evaluation) 
    {
        item.PeriodId = newPeriodId;
        db.Evaluations.Add(item);
    }
```

Basically, item is out of scope as it is not on the next line.